# Fluentd logs not working with multiple <match>

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

We have ElasticSearch FluentD Kibana Stack in our K8s, We are using different source for taking logs and matching it to different Elasticsearch host to get our logs bifurcated .
All was working fine until one of our elastic (elastic-audit) is down and now none of logs are getting pushed which has been mentioned on the fluentd config.

Not sure how can 1 elastic cluster can affect other cluster which are configured on same fluentd configuration file? We tried to remove the impacted tag from the configuration which is in our case "AUDIT_LOG" from filter and match , after which the logs started pushing from other tags.

Need to get FluentD working with all tags in it

```
NAMESPACE       NAME       HEALTH   NODES   VERSION   PHASE   AGE
dm-elastic      dm-eck     green    5       7.2.0     Ready   252d
elastic-audit   da-audit   red              7.4.0     Ready   263d
monitoring      da-eck     green    3       7.2.0     Ready   264d
moss-elastic    moss-eck   green    7       7.2.0     Ready   252d
```

**Error Logs**

```
2021-06-30 08:55:41 +0000 [warn]: [elasticsearch-auditlog] Remaining retry: 5. Retry to communicate after 1024 second(s).
2021-06-30 09:29:49 +0000 [warn]: [elasticsearch-auditlog] Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
2021-06-30 09:29:49 +0000 [warn]: [elasticsearch-auditlog] Remaining retry: 4. Retry to communicate after 2048 second(s).
```

**FLUENTD Config**

```
  containers.input.conf: |-
    <source>
      @id fluentd-containers.log
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/*.log
      exclude_path /var/log/containers/fluentd*.log
      pos_file /var/log/es-containers.log.pos
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      tag kubernetes.*
      format json
      read_from_head true
    </source>

  system.input.conf: |-
    # Example:
    # 2015-12-21 23:17:22,066 [salt.state       ][INFO    ] Completed state [net.ipv4.ip_forward] at time 23:17:22.066081

    <source>
      @id startupscript.log
      @type tail
      format syslog
      path /var/log/startupscript.log
      pos_file /var/log/es-startupscript.log.pos
      tag startupscript
    </source>
    
    <source>
      @id kubelet.log
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/kubelet.log
      pos_file /var/log/es-kubelet.log.pos
      tag kubelet
    </source>

  
    # Logs from systemd-journal for interesting services.
    # TODO(random-liu): Remove this after cri container runtime rolls out.
    <source>
      @id journald-docker
      @type systemd
      matches [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "docker.service" }]
      <storage>
        @type local
        persistent true
      </storage>
      read_from_head true
      tag docker
    </source>
    <source>
     @id haproxy-ingress
     @type syslog
     port 5140
     bind 0.0.0.0
     tag haproxy
     <parse>
       @type syslog
       message_format rfc5424
       rfc5424_time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
     </parse>
    </source>

    <source>
      @id journald-kubelet
      @type systemd
      matches [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "kubelet.service" }]
      <storage>
        @type local
        persistent true
      </storage>
      read_from_head true
      tag kubelet
    </source>



  forward.input.conf: |-
    # Takes the messages sent over TCP
    <source>
      @type forward
    </source>

  monitoring.conf: |-
    # Prometheus Exporter Plugin
    # input plugin that exports metrics
    <source>
      @type prometheus
    </source>

    <source>
      @type monitor_agent
    </source>

    # input plugin that collects metrics from MonitorAgent
    <source>
      @type prometheus_monitor
      <labels>
        host ${hostname}
      </labels>
    </source>

    # input plugin that collects metrics for output plugin
    <source>
      @type prometheus_output_monitor
      <labels>
        host ${hostname}
      </labels>
    </source>

    # input plugin that collects metrics for in_tail plugin
    <source>
      @type prometheus_tail_monitor
      <labels>
        host ${hostname}
      </labels>
    </source>

  output.conf: |-
    <filter kubernetes.**>
      @type concat
      key log
      separator ""
      stream_identity_key tag
      multiline_start_regexp /^time=/
      flush_interval 5
      timeout_label @NORMAL
    </filter>
    <match **>
      @type relabel
      @label @NORMAL
    </match>
    <label @NORMAL>
        <match kubernetes.**>
          @type rewrite_tag_filter
          <rule>
            key log
            pattern (tag=(AUDIT_LOG|CUSTOMER_AUDIT_LOG)|"log_type":"AUDIT_LOG")
            tag auditlog.${tag}
          </rule>
          <rule>
            key log
            pattern tag=PARTNER_AUDIT_LOG
            tag partner-auditlog.${tag}
          </rule>
          <rule>
            key log
            pattern tag=MAINTENANCE_AUDIT_LOG
            tag maintenance-auditlog.${tag}
          </rule>
          <rule>
            key log
            pattern ^time=".*?".*
            tag daas_service.${tag}
          </rule>
          <rule>
            key log
            pattern ^time=".*?".*
            tag other_service.${tag}
            invert true
          </rule>
        </match>
        # Enriches records with Kubernetes metadata
        <filter {daas_service,other_service}.kubernetes.**>
          @type kubernetes_metadata
        </filter>
        <filter {daas_service,other_service}.kubernetes.**>
          @type throttle
          group_key kubernetes.pod_name
          group_bucket_period_s   60
          group_bucket_limit      6000
        </filter>         
        <filter daas_service.kubernetes.**>
          @type kvp
          parse_key log
          fields_key log_field
          pattern "([a-zA-Z_-]\\w*)=((['\"])(?:^(?:\\3)|[^\\\\]|\\\\.)*?(\\3)|[\\w.@$%/+-]*)"
        </filter>
        <filter daas_service.kubernetes.**>
          @type record_modifier
          <record>
            dummy ${if record.has_key?('log_field') and record['log_field'].has_key?('time'); record['@timestamp']=record['log_field']['time']; record['log_field'].delete('time'); end; nil}
            dummy2 ${begin; t = Time.parse record['@timestamp']; record['@timestamp'] = t.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ'); rescue; record.delete('@timestamp'); end; nil}
          </record>
          remove_keys dummy,dummy2
        </filter>    
        <filter auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @type kvp
          parse_key log
          pattern "([a-zA-Z_-]\\w*)=((['\"])(?:^(?:\\3)|[^\\\\]|\\\\.)*?(\\3)|[\\w.@$%/+-]*)"
        </filter>
        <filter auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @type record_modifier
          <record>
            dummy ${if record.has_key?('time'); record['@timestamp']=record['time']; record.delete('time'); end; nil}
            dummy2 ${begin; t = Time.parse record['@timestamp']; record['@timestamp'] = t.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ'); rescue; record.delete('@timestamp'); end; nil}
            levelinfo ${if record.has_key?('level'); record['level']='info'; end; nil}
          </record>
          remove_keys dummy,dummy2,levelinfo
        </filter>
        <filter partner-auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @type kvp
          parse_key log
          pattern "([a-zA-Z_-]\\w*)=((['\"])(?:^(?:\\3)|[^\\\\]|\\\\.)*?(\\3)|[\\w.@$%/+-]*)"
        </filter>
        <filter partner-auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @type record_modifier
          <record>
            dummy ${if record.has_key?('time'); record['@timestamp']=record['time']; record.delete('time'); end; nil}
            dummy2 ${begin; t = Time.parse record['@timestamp']; record['@timestamp'] = t.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ'); rescue; record.delete('@timestamp'); end; nil}
            levelinfo ${if record.has_key?('level'); record['level']='info'; end; nil}
          </record>
          remove_keys dummy,dummy2,levelinfo
        </filter>
        <filter maintenance-auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @type kvp
          parse_key log
          pattern "([a-zA-Z_-]\\w*)=((['\"])(?:^(?:\\3)|[^\\\\]|\\\\.)*?(\\3)|[\\w.@$%/+-]*)"
        </filter>
        <filter maintenance-auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @type record_modifier
          <record>
            dummy ${if record.has_key?('time'); record['@timestamp']=record['time']; record.delete('time'); end; nil}
            dummy2 ${begin; t = Time.parse record['@timestamp']; record['@timestamp'] = t.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ'); rescue; record.delete('@timestamp'); end; nil}
            levelinfo ${if record.has_key?('level'); record['level']='info'; end; nil}
          </record>
          remove_keys dummy,dummy2,levelinfo
        </filter>
        <filter haproxy.**>
          @type parser
          key_name message
          reserve_data true
          reserve_time true
          emit_invalid_record_to_error false
          <parse>
            @type multi_format
            <pattern>
              format regexp
              # Examples
              # 10.2.1.0:31654 [06/Nov/2019:13:21:05.569] httpsfront default-paas-secure-443/10.20.48.136:443 1/0/642 3670 SD 3/2/0/0/0 0/0
              expression /^(?<remoteAddress>[\w\.]+:\d+) \[(?<requestDate>[^\]]*)\] httpsfront (?<namespace>[\w]+)-(?<service>[\w-]+)\/(?<backendAddress>[\w\.]+:\d+) (?<waitTime>\d+)\/(?<backendConnectTime>\d+)\/(?<responseTime>\d+) (?<responseBytes>\d+) (?<terminationState>[\w-]+) (?<actconn>\d+)\/(?<feconn>\d+)\/(?<beconn>\d+)\/(?<srvconn>\d+)\/(?<retries>\d+) (?<srvqueue>\d+)\/(?<backendQueue>\d+)$/
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
              format regexp
              expression /^(?<remoteAddress>[\w\.]+:\d+) \[(?<requestDate>[^\]]*)\] httpfront-(?<domain>[\w-.]+)~ (?<namespace>kube-system|[\w]+)-(?<service>[\w-]+)(-[\d]+)?\/[\w-]+ (?<requestReadTime>\d+)\/(?<waitTime>\d+)\/(?<backendConnectTime>\d+)\/(?<backendResponseTime>\d+)\/(?<responseTime>\d+) (?<statusCode>\d+) (?<responseBytes>\d+) (?<reqCookie>[\w-]+) (?<resCookie>[\w-]+) (?<terminationState>[\w-]+) (?<actconn>\d+)\/(?<feconn>\d+)\/(?<beconn>\d+)\/(?<srvconn>\d+)\/(?<retries>\d+) (?<srvqueue>\d+)\/(?<backendQueue>\d+) "(?<method>[A-Z]+) (?<url>[^ ]+) (?<httpVersion>[^ ]+)"$/
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
              format regexp
              # Examples:
              # Connect from 172.20.59.142:13201 to 172.20.59.142:31916 (httpfront/HTTP)
              # Connect from 10.0.1.2:33312 to 10.0.3.31:8012 (www/HTTP)
              expression /^Connect from (?<remoteAddress>[\w\.]+:\d+) to (?<backendAddress>[\w\.]+:\d+) \((?<frontend>[\w]+)\/(?<mode>[\w]+)\)$/
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
              format regexp
              # Examples:
              # Server kube-system-fluentd-http-http-input/server0002 is going DOWN for maintenance. 3 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
              # Server kube-system-fluentd-http-http-input/server0001 is going DOWN for maintenance. 2 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
              expression /^Server (?<namespace>kube-system|[\w]+)-(?<service>[\w-]+)\/[\w-]+ is going DOWN for maintenance. (?<remainingActive>\d+) active and (?<remainingBackup>\d+) backup servers left. (?<activeSessions>\d+) sessions active, (?<requeued>\d+) requeued, (?<remainingInQueue>\d+) remaining in queue.$/
            </pattern>


            <pattern>
              format regexp
              # Examples: 
              # "10.2.2.0:60889 [06/Nov/2019:13:54:54.904] httpfront-shared-frontend/3: SSL handshake failure" 
              expression /^(?<remoteAddress>[\w\.]+:\d+) \[(?<requestDate>[^\]]*)\] (?<frontend>[\w-]+\/\d+): (?<msg>[\w].*)$/
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
              format regexp
              # Examples:
              # Server kube-system-fluentd-http-http-input/server0003 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: \"Connection refused\", check duration: 0ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
              # Server kube-system-fluentd-http-http-input/server0003 is UP, reason: Layer4 check passed, check duration: 0ms. 3 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
              expression /^Server (?<namespace>kube-system|[\w]+)-(?<service>[\w-]+)\/[\w-]+ is (?<status>[\w]+), reason: (?<reason>[^,]+), (info: "(?<info>[^"]+)", )?check duration: (?<checkDuration>[^.]+). (?<remainingActive>\d+) active and (?<remainingBackup>\d+) backup servers (left|online). ((?<activeSessions>\d+) sessions active, )?(?<requeued>\d+) (sessions )?requeued, (?<remainingInQueue>\d+) (remaining|total) in queue.$/
            </pattern>
          </parse>
        </filter>
        <match auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @id elasticsearch-auditlog
          @type elasticsearch
          @log_level info
          include_tag_key true
          host elastic.audit.{{ required "management Domain" .Values.mgmt_domain }}
          port 443
          user "#{ENV['ELASTIC_USER']}"
          password "#{ENV['ELASTIC_PASSWORD']}"
          scheme "https"
          ssl_verify false
          type_name _doc
          ssl_version TLSv1_2
          time_precision 3 
          logstash_format true
          logstash_prefix auditlog
          reconnect_on_error true
          request_timeout 30s
          bulk_message_request_threshold -1
          <buffer>
            @type file
            path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/auditlog.system.buffer
            flush_mode interval
            retry_type exponential_backoff
            flush_thread_count 2
            flush_interval 5s
            retry_max_interval 30
            chunk_limit_size 10M
            total_limit_size 10G
            queued_chunks_limit_size 100
            overflow_action throw_exception
          </buffer>
        </match>
        <match partner-auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @id elasticsearch-partner-auditlog
          @type elasticsearch
          @log_level info
          include_tag_key true
          host elastic.audit.{{ required "management Domain" .Values.mgmt_domain }}
          port 443
          user "#{ENV['ELASTIC_USER']}"
          password "#{ENV['ELASTIC_PASSWORD']}"
          scheme "https"
          ssl_verify false
          ssl_version TLSv1_2
          type_name _doc
          time_precision 3 
          logstash_format true
          logstash_prefix partner-auditlog
          reconnect_on_error true
          request_timeout 30s
          bulk_message_request_threshold -1
          <buffer>
            @type file
            path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/partner-auditlog.system.buffer
            flush_mode interval
            retry_type exponential_backoff
            flush_thread_count 2
            flush_interval 5s
            retry_max_interval 30
            chunk_limit_size 10M
            total_limit_size 10G
            queued_chunks_limit_size 100
            overflow_action throw_exception
          </buffer>
        </match>
        <match maintenance-auditlog.kubernetes.**>
          @id elasticsearch-maintenance-auditlog
          @type elasticsearch
          @log_level info
          include_tag_key true
          user "#{ENV['ELASTIC_USER']}"
          password "#{ENV['ELASTIC_PASSWORD']}"
          scheme "https"
          ssl_verify false
          ssl_version TLSv1_2
          type_name _doc
          host elastic.audit.{{ required "management Domain" .Values.mgmt_domain }} 
          port 443
          time_precision 3 
          logstash_format true
          logstash_prefix maintenance-auditlog
          reconnect_on_error true
          request_timeout 30s
          bulk_message_request_threshold -1
          <buffer>
            @type file
            path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/maintenance-auditlog.system.buffer
            flush_mode interval
            retry_type exponential_backoff
            flush_thread_count 2
            flush_interval 5s
            retry_max_interval 30
            chunk_limit_size 10M
            total_limit_size 1G
            queued_chunks_limit_size 100
            overflow_action throw_exception
          </buffer>
        </match>
        <match haproxy.**>
          @id elasticsearch-haproxy
          @type elasticsearch
          @log_level info
          include_tag_key true
          user "#{ENV['ELASTIC_USER']}"
          password "#{ENV['ELASTIC_PASSWORD']}"
          scheme "https"
          type_name _doc
          ssl_verify false
          ssl_version TLSv1_2
          host da-eck-es-http.monitoring 
          port 9200
          time_precision 3 
          logstash_format true
          logstash_prefix haproxy
          reconnect_on_error true
          request_timeout 30s
          bulk_message_request_threshold -1
          <buffer>
            @type memory
            flush_mode interval
            retry_type exponential_backoff
            flush_thread_count 2
            flush_interval 5s
            retry_max_interval 20
            retry_max_times 10
            chunk_limit_size 10M
            total_limit_size 100M
            queued_chunks_limit_size 100
            overflow_action throw_exception
          </buffer>
        </match>
        <match **>
          @id elasticsearch
          @type elasticsearch
          @log_level info
          include_tag_key true
          type_name _doc
          host da-eck-es-http.monitoring
          port 9200
          user "#{ENV['ELASTIC_USER']}"
          password "#{ENV['ELASTIC_PASSWORD']}"
          scheme "https"
          ssl_verify false
          ssl_version TLSv1_2
          time_precision 3 
          logstash_format true
          reconnect_on_error true
          request_timeout 30s     
          bulk_message_request_threshold -1
          <buffer>
            @type memory
            flush_mode interval
            retry_type exponential_backoff
            flush_thread_count 2
            flush_interval 5s
            retry_max_interval 30
            chunk_limit_size 10M
            retry_max_times 10
            total_limit_size 1G
            queued_chunks_limit_size 100
            overflow_action throw_exception
          </buffer>
        </match>
    </label>
```

Comment: Did you test this scenario using the [copy](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/copy) output plugin?